# UNNotificationServiceExtension, Locale returns wrong languageCode

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, unnotificationserviceextension

I am trying to localize push notifications, passing in data localization map with key as a language code.
For the modification notification using UNNotificationServiceExtension, but stuck on the issue: `Locale.current.languageCode` always returns **en** (calling from UNNotificationServiceExtension). My phone and app locale is set to **uk**.

I know that a possible solution can be to store the language code in the UserDefaults, but it seems to me like a workaround. Has someone figured out the issue to get the correct language code from the extension?

[Here is a debug info from service extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b774O.png)